# Android building: No rule to make target `frameworks/base/preloaded-classes

Tags: android, c, linux, build

I'm trying to build a third party Android system base on Android4.4_r1.2. Encountering this error at the very beginning. Which file should I check and how to fix this error?

```
make: *** No rule to make target `frameworks/base/preloaded-classes', needed by `out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar'.  Stop.
```

Thanks for anyone that help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow following steps that will definitely work
1. make clean (for removing out folder)
2. make otapackage  (for building full android)

I also faced this kind of issues in past, but not get quick solution.